# docker push, how to see detailed interaction with registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I'm pushing an image to a private registry and I would like to see details about the interaction with that registry. I tried docker -D, --debug, but that doesn't show any details.

```
/ # docker -D push registry.company.com:8443/hello-world:test
The push refers to a repository [registry.company.com:8443/hello-world]
45761469c965: Layer already exists
test: digest: sha256:9fa82f24cbb11b6b80d5c88e0e10c3306707d97ff862a3018f22f9b49cef303a size: 524
```

How can I show details about the docker client interacting with my private registry?

Comment: Strange that a user would delete his answer and all comments and then down vote the question.

Answer (score 8):

You would normally look in the docker daemon logs. Enable debug mode (in docker daemon) to see a bit more info. The client is asking your docker daemon to push the image to the repo, so your docker client has very little to do with this process.

Comment: The only log I see from the daemon is a DNS lookup. I'm struggling to figure out how to enable debug logging in the docker daemon on Mac OSX Sierra.

Comment: Preferences -> Daemon -> Advanced. Here you can inject json.

Comment: Thanks. I actually have debug: true set there, but the logs don't include any details about interactions with the registry other than the DNS lookup.

Comment: You could look in the registry logs? What exactly are you looking for in the logs?

Comment: I'm getting the error "unauthorized: BAD_CREDENTIAL" when I try to push. The registry is set to work anonymously, so I'm trying to figure out if the docker client is sending credentials.

Comment: Check with whoever made the registry you are currently using. I know Artifactory have had problems with this in the past. If the repo required auth before you might have credentials in `~/.docker/config.json` messing things up as well.